# How to stop onClick running on razor page load

Tags: html, razor

I have the following code in my .cshtml file

```html
<form asp-page-handler="button"  method="post">
    <label class="form-label">Username</label>
    <input  name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" />
    <button class=button-gap onclick="@grabStats()">Find stats</button>   
</form>
```

The problem is the function grabStats() runs on pageLoad and returns an error

Is there a reason why an onclick event is fired when the page loads without the button being clicked?

For more clarity:

```cs
@functions{
    private async Task<string> Stats()
    {

        var username  = Request.Form["username"];
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Activity chooser");
         String url = "https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=" + username;
          HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
          response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
          string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return responseBody;
    }




    private String grabStats()
    {

        var statsRaw = Stats().Result;

        Models.Player player = new Models.Player();
        return ""; //Later return useful stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this `grabStats` function in the client-side JavaScript code, or the server-side C# code?  What's the error?

Comment: Hi, sorry I should have specified more, its in the server-side C# code

The error is due to performing .Result on a Task<string> I think without it having a value (hence why I'm trying to stop the onclick firing before page load, not sure if that's the correct way of doing it or not.

I've edited my main post

Comment: @D74: The duplicate uses PHP for its examples but the concept is identical and language agnostic.  The server-side code runs on the server before the page is even sent to the client.  What you’re doing is executing that function server-side and setting whatever it returns as the client-side click handler.  Whatever the goal is, the implementation needs to be re-thought.

Comment: As an aside, calling .Result on a Task is almost always the wrong approach, unless you really know what’s going on under the hood.  Taking a step back… If this operation should be performed when a button is clicked, you’re probably looking to use AJAX (if it needs to be server-side at all).  If the operation is async, make it async all the way up to the endpoint being invoked by the AJAX request.

Comment: Awesome thankyou, i'll take a read through and get a better understanding on both issues